# Javascript - Google Maps Simple Map not rendering tiles on Webserver - works local tho

Tags: javascript, css, asynchronous

I tried embedding Google Maps javascript API to my website. Tried it local and it worked fine but as soon as i try it on my webserver the tiles wont load.
Heres the simple code im using:

```
#map { height: 250px; }
<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 49.101670, lng: 9.212140},
zoom: 15
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: {lat: 49.101670, lng: 9.212140},
map: map,
title: 'OPTIKHAUS FLEIN'
});

}

</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCrIgqoG8GX88lnjBFX_H_UH6VpK90khSA&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Here is how it looks like on the website

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSuvH.png)

even the marker is showing up.

thanks in advance

Comment: `<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?   key=AIzaSyCrIgqoG8GX88lnjBFX_H_UH6VpK90khSA&callback=initMap">
</script>` - remove spaces betwen `js? key=`

Comment: Have u changed anything in that codeline?

Comment: yes, see example under

Answer (score 0):

You have extra spaces in url - js?key. Check my snippet. I update this line `"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCrIgqoG8GX88lnjBFX_H_UH6VpK90khSA&callback=initMap"` only

```css
#map { height: 250px; }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 49.101670, lng: 9.212140},
zoom: 15
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: {lat: 49.101670, lng: 9.212140},
map: map,
title: 'OPTIKHAUS FLEIN'
});

}

</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCrIgqoG8GX88lnjBFX_H_UH6VpK90khSA&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry the space showed up when i copied the code in here. there is no space in my code tho

Comment: No, sadly the tiles are still not rendering.